# NextJS Deploy (Release) error on Task with Azure Web App Deploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-devops, next.js

hope to get some help as I'm struggling to get a NextJS or any type of node project to successfully deploy on Azure with DevOps pipeline.

I have all the steps and configuration working on the Repo PR to then run a build and finally the triggered Release. It will pull down the zip artifact from the build, however I always get an error on the agent job for the task "Azure Web App Deploy".

In short the job appears to always run a yarn install command vs. the Startup Command setting.

My setup is as follows:
[Task Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKwTQ.png)

[Azure Web App Deploy task error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdhJz.png)

Tried with different Startup commands, which none display in the task.

Comment: I think it's a fluke, but also added to the Application Config settings the following:

-SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT FALSE
-build-remote true

Answer (score 0):

I added the following in the "Application and Configuration Settings" section of the task:

```
    -SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT FALSE
    -build-remote true
```